# Android Emulator - proxy is unreachable

Tags: android-studio, proxy, android-emulator

I need to set up a proxy in the Android Emulator from Android Studio on macOS; however, I am encountering the error 'Proxy is unreachable.' In the log, the following messages appear:

```
WARNING | Could not connect to proxy at :8080: No such file or directory !
WARNING | Proxy will be ignored !
```

[image: screenshot from settings]

I have also attempted to configure the proxy directly in Android Studio. After verifying the connection there, everything works, but unfortunately in the emulator doesn't.

Another approach I tried was running the emulator from the terminal and adding the flag `-http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080`, but I experienced the same result.

Could someone give me some hints, where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by downgrading emulator version to `Android Emulator (32.1.13) Stable` - [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive).
Before deleting original emulator, verify that this version works:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Android/Sdk/ ./emulator -avd EMU
```

Comment: It looks like google shipped a bug breaking the emulator's proxy sometime in 2023. Downgrading the emulator seems like the workaround for now. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/316936484

Answer (score 0):

I changed **proxy hostname** to my **host machine**, and it works. Please check below image.

[image]